# Set Representation of $\bigcap\limits_{A\subseteq C}C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Let $G$ be a group and $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq G$. Let 
$M(A)=\bigcap_{A\subseteq C}C$ where $C$ is any subset of $G$ such that $c^k\in C$ for all $c\in C$ and $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ and if there is $g\in G$ such that 
$g^k=\prod_{i=1}^mc_i^{k_i}$ and $k=\sum_{i=1}^mk_i$ 
for $c_i\in C$ and $k_i\in\mathbb N$, then $g\in C$.

How to prove that
$$M(A)=\left\{g\in G:g^n=\prod_{i=1}^ma_i^{n_i},a_i\in A,n_i\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\},n\in\mathbb N\right\}?\tag{*}$$

Also I proved that the equality in $(*)$ holds, if we redefine $M(A)$ by adding a third condition to $C$, namely, if there is $k\in\mathbb N$ and $g\in G$ such that $g^k\in C$ then $g\in C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true, because your "third condition" always holds for sets $C$ satisfying your first two conditions.  Indeed, if $C$ is nonempty (say $c\in C$) and satisfies your first two conditions, then it contains $c^0=1$.  Now suppose $g^k\in C$ for some $k>0$.  Note that $$g^k=(g^k)^1\cdot 1^{k-1},$$ so by the second condition on $C$ (with $m=2$, $k_1=1$, and $k_2=k-1$), $g\in C$.

Comment: I was just about to comment that lol nice, +1